# Django multi language model / filter post by languages

Tags: django

There is my simple blog model;

```
class Article(models.Model):

    author = models.ForeignKey("auth.User",on_delete = models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Author")
    title_en = models.CharField(max_length = 120, verbose_name="Title_En")
    title_de = models.CharField(max_length = 120, verbose_name="Title_De")
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    content_en = RichTextField(verbose_name="Content_En")
    content_de = RichTextField(verbose_name="Content_De")
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Created Date")
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Add Photo (.jpg .png)")
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length = 130)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I use url's with language like this;

domainname.com/en/
domainname.com/de/

For example, how can I show only the contents that belong to title_de and content_de in the domainname.com/de urls?

How can I do filtering with language? Is there an easy solution to this?
(I usage django 2.1.2. i try django-modeltranslation or others dont work this django version...)

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering based on keyward argument is one of the option for this problem.I would prefer to add a language field  **'EN'** or '**DE'** rather than repeating same kind of title and content field and filtering based on that. For example,

#### Article Model can be like

```
class Article(models.Model):
     LANGUAGE_TYPES = (
    ('EN', 'EN'),
    ('DE', 'DE'),
     )

    author = models.ForeignKey("auth.User",on_delete = models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Author")
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 120, verbose_name="Title")
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    content = RichTextField(verbose_name="Content")
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Created Date")
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Add Photo (.jpg .png)")
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length = 130)
    language = models.CharField(
    max_length=10, choices=LANGUAGE_TYPES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

#### Our urls can be like

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import (ArticleView)

urlpatterns = [
    path('article/<slug:type>/', ArticleView.as_view(), name='article'),
]
```

#### And Our view can be like

```
from rest_framework import views, status
from .serializers import ArticleSerializer
from .models import Article

class ArticleView(views.APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        article_language_type = self.kwargs.get('type', None)
        articles = Article.objects.filter(language=article_language_type)
        serializer = ArticleSerializer(articles, many=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
              return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: thank you so much for help. I'll do it immediately. thank you so much. you are the best!

Answer (score 5):

You can create a [descriptor class](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) that wraps the translated fields e.g.,

```
from django.utils import translation

class TranslatedField:
    def __init__(self, field_name):
         self.partial_field_name = field_name

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        return getattr(obj, self.field_name)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        return setattr(obj, self.field_name,  value)

    @property
    def field_name(self):
        language_code = translation.get_language()
        rerurn self.partial_field_name + '_' + language_code

class Article(models.Model):

    title_en = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    title_de = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    title = Translated Field('title')
```

Then you can do

```
article = Article.objects.create(
    title_en='In english',
    title_de='In German'
)

print(article.title)  # 'In english'
translation.set_language('de')
print(article.title)  # 'In German'
article.title = 'In German!'
print(article.title)  # 'In German!'
translation.set_language('en')
print(article.title)  # 'In english'
```

(Untested, so there may be typos)

I would use something out of the box like https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation